# CTE vs subquery, which one is efficient?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
SELECT col, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) as total_count FROM table
```

This query executes subquery for every row, right?

Now if we have

```
;WITH CTE(total_count) AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
)
SELECT col, (SELECT total_count FROM CTE) FROM table;
```

Will be second method more efficient? Will CTE execute `COUNT(*)` only once and then SELECT uses it as prepared value?  or in second case also executed `COUNT(*)` for each row?

Comment: you should try it yourself on your data and tell us = )

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Different products may to this in different ways.)

Comment: I'm basically use SQL-Server or Oracle

Comment: SQL Server and Oracle optimize CTEs in very different ways.  The answer may differ by database.

Comment: Gordon Linoff Then I choose Oracle ))

Comment: I would be very surprised if those two statements end up with vastly different execution plans. (Also: there is no need to put the statement delimiter at the beginning of a statement, you only need `;` at the end of a statement)

Comment: A CTE permits the Oracle optimizer to materialize the result (i.e. create a temporary table and store results in it). I don't know whether Oracle is able to materialize also subquery results. If not then CTE can be more efficient - but this would not apply for your example.

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit `but this would not apply for your example.` Why, whats wrong with this example ?

Comment: For efficiency, there are methods of counting table rows that are much faster than COUNT(*) e.g SQL Server: SELECT SUM (row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('table') AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1)

Comment: I think (but again I am not sure) CTE are only materialized if they are used more than once in main query - which is not the case in your example.

Comment: @cloudsafe - depends how much you care about accuracy [row_count ...The approximate number of rows in the partition.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql)

Comment: @LuisDaSilva you are using SQL-Server, in Oracle is `TABLE` reserved,  you must double quote it `select * from "TABLE";`:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Oracle the surest way is to observe the behaviour of the statements with extended statistics.

Do do so first increase the statistics level to `ALL`

```
 alter session set statistics_level=all;
```

Then run both statements (fetching all rows) and [find the SQL_ID  of those statements](https://www.pythian.com/blog/simple-and-quick-way-to-get-sql_id-of-query-in-oracle/)

Finally display the statistics using following statement (passing the proper SQL_ID):

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('your SQL_ID here',null,'ALLSTATS LAST'));
```

This gives for my test table

```
SQL_ID  5n0sdcu8347j9, child number 0
-------------------------------------
SELECT    col, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1) as total_count FROM t1

Plan hash value: 1306093980

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |      1 |        |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |     351 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |     338 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |      1 |   1061 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |     338 |
|   3 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL | T1   |      1 |   1061 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |     351 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and

```
SQL_ID  fs0h660f08bj6, child number 0
-------------------------------------
WITH CTE(total_count) AS (     SELECT   COUNT(*) FROM t1 ) SELECT col, 
(SELECT total_count FROM CTE) FROM t1

Plan hash value: 1223456497

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |      1 |        |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |     351 |
|   1 |  VIEW               |      |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |     338 |
|   2 |   SORT AGGREGATE    |      |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |     338 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |      1 |   1061 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |     338 |
|   4 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL  | T1   |      1 |   1061 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |     351 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the plans are slightly different, but in both cases the `FULL TABLE SCAN` is started only once (column *Starts* = 1). Which gives no real difference.

For purpose of camparison I run also a correlated subquery, which gives a complete different picture with high number of Starts (of FTS)

```
SQL_ID  cbvwd6pm6699m, child number 0
-------------------------------------
SELECT col, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 where col = a.col) as total_count 
FROM t1 a

Plan hash value: 1306093980

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |      1 |        |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |     351 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |   1000 |      1 |   1000 |00:00:00.31 |     338K|
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |   1000 |     11 |   1000 |00:00:00.31 |     338K|
|   3 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL | T1   |      1 |   1061 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |     351 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("COL"=:B1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the query optimizer in both Oracle and SQL Server will recognize that the count query is not correlated, compute it once, and then use the cached result throughout the execution of the outer query.

Also, the CTE won't change anything as far as I know, since at execution time the code inside it will basically just be inlined into the actual outer query.

Here is a [reference](http://www.praetoriate.com/t_op_sql_noncorrelated.htm) for Oracle which mentions that a non correlated subquery will be executed once and cached, except in cases where the outer query only has a few rows.  In that case, it might not be cached because there isn't much of a penalty in executing the count subquery multiple times.